# Showing a file tree view of a commit in tig

Tags: git, tig

I'm using tig and would like to see the list of changed files in a commit, possibly drilling down to a diff view of a specific file, yet I haven't found a way to do this. Is it possible, or is only the diff view available on a commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gentleman behind tig has graciously created a dedicated view log: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323680/2916086

Thank you sir!

---

UPDATE: 
pipe in the data you want tig to format. For example:

```
> git log --stat|tig
> alias tigstat='git log --stat|tig'
> tigstat
```

---

Basically, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the commit you are interested, while in the default view of tig.

In detail:

1. highlight a commit in the default view, using the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> cursor keys.
2. press <kbd>enter</kbd> on a commit in the default view. Then use up and down or the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys to navigate the diff.

The list of changed files should be at the top of the diff.

See http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html#viewer for more info

---

You can also get this information using:

```
git log --stat
git log --stat A_COMMIT_SHA
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for something like a dedicated view, but the aggregate will do the job too, I guess.

Comment: @StavrosKorokithakis, consider typing the following by hand after you run `tig`: `:!git log --stat`

Comment: Would that be what you're looking for?

Comment: Almost, I was hoping tig would have such a display with a dedicated patch or diff view, e.g. like gitg does.

Comment: Updating the answer to include a workaround for what you want

Answer (score 4):

Tig has a dedicated log view since version 1.2.
Use `tig log` to start it.

While it does not allow you to jump directly into a file diff, pressing Enter will open the commit diff from where you can then jump to the file you are interested by highlighting the file and pressing Enter.